# No search data in Google Analytics or Webmasters

Tags: google-analytics, google-search

I have a domain that has been registered in Google Webmasters and using Google Analytics for over 4 months.

I get lots of analytics data, but am getting no information on Google searches in Webmasters, or Queries in Search Engine Optimisation in Analytics, even though I am getting keywords for traffic coming to my site from search engines.

I have a test sub-domain with the same setup (except not HTTPS) that is getting some of this information through, even with much less data and visits.

What could be wrong to stop me getting this information?

Answer (score 1):

Did you ["Associate a Webmaster Tools site with a Google Analytics web property"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1120006)?

Comment: Yes, have done this.

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure you have completed webmaster verification for your domain

Comment: Yes, have done this.